# How to hide top space showing previous ViewController hierarchy on Xcode iOS Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

This case not occurs on iPhone 6 but, occurs on iPhone 8 or higher. Using a segue of kind `Show Detail` to navigate from ViewController1 to ViewController2 there are a space showing the previous ViewController1 on top screen like image below:

[image: view controller screenshot]

How can I hide this space?

I tried:

1. Use all presentation types on ViewController2 (Automatic, FullScreen...)
2. Size master

Comment: How you used full screen ?

Comment: Are you presenting from storyboard or from code ?

Comment: Using storyboard. ViewController2 -> Attributes Inspector -> Presentation -> FullScreen

Comment: No ... You need to tap the segue ... tap segue and instead of show detail ... make it `modal`... it will show `presentationStyle` convert it to `full screen`

Comment: use giff to understand better ... which i shared in answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try presenting it programatically as (set it in previous view controller):

```
let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you don't want to use navigation controller then skip first step.

Comment: solved the problem. I was using modal..Style on VC.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `modalPresentationStyle` of the `UIViewController` you're presenting as `fullScreen`.

```
class PresentingViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try show instead if showDetail? Also, try presenting the controller programmatically?

Comment: Are you sure about that? If you're presenting programmatically it should work. `present(PresentingViewController(), animated: true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in storyboard...First tap the `segue`...first change kind to Modal... And then presentation to full screen ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
let nav = UINavigationController()
let ctrl = ViewController1()

nav.pushViewController(ctrl, animated: true)
nav.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.showDetailViewController(nav, sender: self)
nav.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
```

This covers the complete screen when presenting your **controller**.

```
nav.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
```

sets the source view of your **popover** to the size of the view.